# C++ invalid assignment

Tags: c++, variable-assignment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Undefined Behavior and Sequence Points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)

Is there any one know that whether this is valid or not in C++

```
int a = 0;
a = a++;
```

Someone told me that it will generate unknown behavior under C++ standard, did anyone know why, and where in the C++ standard states that? Thanks!

Comment: It's already been noted that the behavior is undefined.  But whatever you're trying to do, there's certainly a better and clearer way to do it.  In this case, a simple `a++;` does what you want with no ambiguity or risk of undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

I've posted it before, and I will post it again:

http://www.slideshare.net/olvemaudal/deep-c

highly recommended for anybody with such questions in mind

Answer (score 1):

The techincal reason why is that you should not modify the same variable twice (either directly or due to side effects) between sequence points.

Here is an [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points) with good answers that clarifies this further and describes sequence points in general.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the standard per se (its probably referenced from the C standard anyway), but here you can read about it:

http://www.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#evaluation-order